# What's the complexity(Big O) of a Ruffini's rule algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o, time-complexity, complexity-theory

What would be the right complexity analysis of the [Ruffini's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruffini%27s_rule)?

Comment: Algorithm of what? As I understood, there are at least three things that you can do with Ruffini's rule.

Comment: If you're just dividing an integer-coefficient polynomial of degree n by a single degree-1 polynomial, that's going to take O(n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding of Ruffini's rule is that it's essentially given by this pseudocode:

```
let b = [];
let last = 0;

for (i from n - 1 to 0) {
    b.add(last + a[n]);
    last = (last + a[n]) * r;
}
let s = last;
```

If we assume that all the coefficients are integers and that multiplications can all be done in time O(1) each, then the runtime of this algorithm will be O(n), since there are n iterations of a loop doing O(1) work each.

In practice, multiplications take longer than this. Specifically, multiplying two integers that are a and b bits long, respectively, usually takes time O(log a log b) unless you use specialized algorithms that run a bit faster than this.

So let's assume that every coefficient, and the number r, are all at most U. On each iteration, we multiply by r and add in U, so the maximum value of last after each iteration will be 0, O(U<sup>2</sup>), O(U<sup>3</sup>), O(U<sup>4</sup>), ..., O(U<sup>n+1</sup>). This means that the multiplications will take time proportional to 0, 2 log U, 3 log U, 4 log U, ..., n log U. Summing up across the multiplications, this takes time O(n<sup>2</sup> log U), so the total work done would be O(n<sup>2</sup> log U).